# Connect web3.py with Ganache

Tags: ganache, web3.py

I am new to this. So, how do I connect web3.py with Ganache. I've got Ganache up and running, smart contract deployed. I would like to interact with it from, lets say, a python shell. So, this is what I get:

```
>>> from web3 import Web3
>>> w3 = Web3(Web3.IPCProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545'))
>>> w3.isConnected()
False
```

I can connect with Ganache using truffle. Is it possible to do it with web3.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545'))
```

Also, make sure that the port is correct (usually ganache-cli listen on 8545)

Source: [web3.py quickstart](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)